# syntax for using user-agent with xidel

Tags: browser

What's the syntax for using user-agent with xidel?
 I want to access the site http://www.ip-tracker.org/.

I have tried this

```
xidel --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0" "http://www.ip-tracker.org" -e '//*[@id="maincontent"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[10]'
```

and I get this error

```
Browser Language:Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

Next to the user agent, browsers send a few other http headers in the negotiation process, one of them being *accept-language*, i.e.

`Accept-Language=en-US`

It sounds like your site refuses to continue serving content if it doesn't get this header information sent to it.

Try `xidel --header "accept-language=en-US"`